# Log4Net - Log to Azure Blob Storage doesn't create logs

Tags: c#, azure, log4net

I'm trying to log information to Azure Blob Storage using this Nuget libraries:

- log4net (2.0.3)
- log4net.Appender.Azure (1.3.0.19665)

My `app.config` file contains:

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>    
  <section type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" name="log4net" />
 </configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="StorageConnectionString" connectionString="!@#$%^&*()" />    
 </connectionStrings>
 ...
 <log4net>
  <appender name="AzureBlobAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AzureBlobAppender, log4net.Appender.Azure">
   <param name="ContainerName" value="Logs"/>
   <param name="DirectoryName" value="logs"/>
   <param name="ConnectionStringName" value="StorageConnectionString" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
   </layout>
 </appender>
 <root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="AzureBlobAppender" />
</root>
```

Appender creates storage container but it's always empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are currently doing development on development PC, better use the cloud emulator by inserting this line as your connection string

```
 <param name="ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
```

If you are currently testing directly into the cloud, you can put the connection string which you can get in your azure portal.